# SQL: Using two dates from other query to select data between date interval

Tags: sql, database, date

I am new to SQL and I am facing a complicated problem.

My table **T2** contains `start_date` and `end_date`, two time stamps. Table **T1** contains a time-stamp ts and values v for that.

I would like to use the pairs of time-stamps in T2 to obtain values v from T1 between those pair of dates. I tried something like below but it will not work. I would appreciate your help with pointing me to the problem.

```
select 
    v, 
    circle_ts 
from t1 
where circle_ts between start_ts 
    and end_ts in (
        select 
            start_ts, 
            end_ts 
        from t2 
        where meter_id = 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alternatively `JOIN` both tables and searched on for values that is between with dates.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.v, a.circle_ts 
FROM    t1 a
        INNER JOIN t2 b
            ON a.circle_ts BETWEEN b.start_ts AND b.end_ts
WHERE   b.meter_id = 10
```